# How to solve jQuery Validation Plugin with dynamic form

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a changeable form depends on the select tag for example

```
 <select id="select_type">
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="4">Audi</option>
 </select>

 <input type="botton" id="check" onclick="validate();" value="Validate">

 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="audio_sampling_rate" id="audio_sampling_rate">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="audio_file" id="audio_file">
 <input type="text"class="form-control"  name="pic_height" id="pic_height"> 
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pic_width" id="pic_width">
```

I have javascript function to classified action to form when user select option for example

```
 function validate(){
  var e = document.getElementById("select_type");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var form = "#form_input";
  if(strUser == '1'){
    //validate audio_sampling_rate
  }else if(strUser == '2'){
    //validate audio_file
  }else if(strUser == '3'){
    //validate pic_height
  }else{
    //validate pic_width
  } 
 }
```

but the problem is i don't know how to implement jQuery Validation Plugin in function validate and 
Each if have different tag to require please give me an example to solve this problem.

Comment: Your HTML is messed up. You have input type "botton" and you end the input tag with a </button>.

Comment: OH i'm sorry i just saw.